# Generate pdf from HTML and SVG

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, svg, cordova

I have some SVG element in my HTML page with some HTML controls. I want to export all in a pdf. The export need to be "correct", I can't, for example, create a picture and create a pdf from it. And the html text need to keep this format, it have to stay selectionnable.

I saw jspdf but it seems hard with SVGs.

So, have you got an idea to do this?

Just for information I work with Phonegap / Angular js on mobile platforms.

Comment: And do you want the rendering to be local? Or?

Comment: Ho yeah sorry, yes I want the rendering to be local

Comment: On mobile, I know of no rendering solution to produce PDF with embedded SVG. iText can do HTML to PDF on mobile but not SVG. RenderX could do that server side but not on mobile.